# fetching db value dynamically in form using jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

In my registration form I have a field called `s_id`. when i will input the `s_id` a field name `s_name` will be filled automatically. actually `s_id` is `id` of a old user and `s_name` is his `name`. So they are in database like `id` and `name` being used as `s_id` and `s_name` for a new user.

Here is my view code

```
<input type="text" name="s_id" id="s_id" onkeyup="get_user_name('id');" />
<input type="text" name="s_name" id="s_name" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function get_user_name(id){
        var data = $('#'+id).val();
           jQuery.ajax({
              url: "<?php echo site_url('welcome/test');?>",
              type: "POST",
              data: { id:Data },
              cache: false,
              dataType: "text",
              success: function(data) {

            $("#name").val(data);            

            }
        });

    }

    </script>
```

What should be the controller and model function structure for this job?

Comment: Side notel: var data = ... not Data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In controller: You just need to echo the result.

Like this:

```
function temp()
{
   $uname=$this->name_of_model->get_username($_POST[['id']);
   foreach($uname->result() as $r)
   {
      echo $r;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have follow this auto compete functionality and it works well for me .http://www.jamipietila.fi/codeigniter-and-autocomplete-with-jquery/ , Hopefully this will help you too.